# Change color Einstein's CV

Tags: color, templates, cv

I'm working on a CV and I adopted this template between those proposed by Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/einsteins-cv/dqstkjsystrm

Unfortunately I do not understand where can I modify the color. Can someone give me an hint?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look into the code of the document class shows: The document class defines four colors and a selection of different color themes. The color themes can be selected by setting an option to the document class. Except for `theme` which seems to be the default color theme, you can try one of these:

```
brownish
mustardish
greenish
aqua
blueish
pinkish
burgundish
```

Just replace `\documentclass[theme]{cv_einstein}` with `\documentclass[brownish]{cv_einstein}` or use one of the other options.

If these color themes don't satisfy your needs, you can also override the colors explicity. The colors are called `darkcolor`, `mediumcolor`, `lightcolor` and `palecolor`. So, you could also type something like the following in your preamble:

```
\definecolor{darkcolor}{named}{red}
\definecolor{mediumcolor}{named}{blue}
\definecolor{lightcolor}{named}{green}
\definecolor{palecolor}{named}{yellow}
```

If you struggle with using the `\definecolor` command, you should check the [manual of the `xcolor` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf).